# Parsing heavily nested JSON in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm connecting to and extracting a JSON via API, but getting stuck parsing beyond a certain point.

I've been able to parse to the sample level included below.  I'd like to extract a list of 'symbols' from the resulting JSON list, but only appear able to do this for individual entities.  I'd like to do it directly if at all possible (ie, avoid just using a loop).

Namely, this works:

```
data[0]['acct']['positions'][1]['i']['symbol']
```

Returning this:

```
Out[100]: 'JNC'
```

But this and this don't:

```
data[0]['acct']['positions'][:]['i']['symbol']

data[0]['acct']['positions'][0:3]['i']['symbol']
```

Both returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-105-72bbee303a08>", line 1, in <module>
    data[0]['securitiesAccount']['positions'][:]['instrument']['symbol']

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Sample JSON below:

```
[{'a': 0.0,
  'b': 1.0,      
  'i': {'desc': 'CASH_EQUIVALENT', 'id': '9ZZZFD104', 'symbol': 'MMDA1'},
  'c': 72.64},
 {'a': 0.0,
  'b': 33.61716,      
  'i': {'desc': 'EQUITY', 'id': '78464A417', 'symbol': 'JNC'},
  'c': 39.59},
 {'a': 0.0,
  'b': 87.81473,      
  'i': {'desc': 'EQUITY', 'id': '921937793', 'symbol': 'BVV'},
  'c': 19.34}]
```

Comment: Because in with `[1]` you are accessing an element in the list. Where `[:]` is the entire list itself and `[0:3]` is a subset of the list. Which need to be accessed with integer indexes.

Comment: Your examples that "don't" do not seem to apply to the sample JSON you provided, since there's no `acct`, `positions` etc. in there. Can you update the example data and example code so that they refer to the same and check whether you still have the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of indexing won't work like it does in NumPy. You can use a list comprehension instead:

```
result = [record['i']['symbol'] for record in data[0]['acct']['positions'][0:3]]
```

Obviously, change `[0:3]` to whatever. If you want all of them, just omit the slice completely.

---

This is what you tried to do originally:

Say you have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
foo = [{'bar': 1}, {'bar': 2}, {'bar': 3}]
```

If you wanted to access `[1, 2, 3]` with your method, it would be something like `foo[:]['bar']`. However, this expression is evaluated left to right, and `foo[:]` would just create a slice of `foo`, doing essentially nothing. Then you try to get the key `'bar'` from `foo`, a list, which will raise an error.

Comment: this is great, thanks...offhand, is there a good reason why the slice the way I originally doesn't work in this circumstance like standard indexing?

Comment: and is there then a concise way to retrieve the data corresponding to the various symbols (eg, data[0][...]['symbol'] = 'BVV'?

Comment: @Chris I made an edit with a small explanation. Unfortunately, I do not believe there is a way to retrieve data like that. A list comprehension or similar is required.

Comment: got it...so there's no way to retrieve the data associated with a given symbol aside from a list comprehension or loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to return a filtered list.

Instead of

```
data[0]['acct']['positions'][:]['i']['symbol']
```

You could use:

```
[ i['i']['symbol'] for i in data[0]['acct'] ]
```

This loops though `data[0]['act']`, and constructs a list of `['i']['symbol']` for each of these.

For a sub part of a list you can use:

```
[ i['i']['symbol'] for i in data[0]['acct'][0:3] ]
```

Modifying this to work with your sample json:

```
data = [
 {'a': 0.0,
  'b': 1.0,      
  'i': {'desc': 'CASH_EQUIVALENT', 'id': '9ZZZFD104', 'symbol': 'MMDA1'},
  'c': 72.64},
 {'a': 0.0,
  'b': 33.61716,      
  'i': {'desc': 'EQUITY', 'id': '78464A417', 'symbol': 'JNC'},
  'c': 39.59},
 {'a': 0.0,
  'b': 87.81473,      
  'i': {'desc': 'EQUITY', 'id': '921937793', 'symbol': 'BVV'},
  'c': 19.34}
 ]
print([ i['i']['symbol'] for i in data[0] ])
```

Prints:

```
['MMDA1', 'JNC', 'BVV']
```